# Rails Active query return most associated products and then the rest without associations - will pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, will-paginate

I'm hoping this would return ALL products beginning with those with the most associations (some products don't have associations):

```
@products = Product.search(params[:search]).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page]).most_popular
```

My models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :associations
  has_many :users, :through => :associations

  scope :most_popular, -> { select("products.*, count(associations.product_id) AS count_popular").joins(:associations).group("products.id").order("count_popular DESC") | Product.all.order("id DESC")}

class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product

  attr_accessible :product_id
end
```

This seems to work when I list everything at once, but I get the error when also using will_pagination pagination:

```
  NoMethodError - undefined method `total_pages' for #<Array:0x007fa5c5baef60>:
```

Comment: try using
@products = Product.most_popular.where(search_conditions).paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh I have edited the post, the problem I have is that the query does not work well with will pagination it seems

Comment: What do you mean by count(associations.product_id) ??? make you question clear

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh count(associations.product_id) is the total number of associations the product belongs to.

Comment: @SabyasachiGhosh I think it was correct to try most_popular at the beginning of the chain, but I get another error instead "NoMethodError - undefined method `dir?' for #<Product:0x007fa5c5e1d490>"

Comment: Please make the question and problem clear.

Comment: Where you are getting the `NoMethodError - undefined method total_pages for #<Array:0x007fa5c5baef60>` .Please post the full error stack.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this

```
require 'will_paginate/array'

@products = Product.search(params[:search]).most_popular.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
```

Apparently will paginate is not good with arrays unless you tell it to.